# Difference between row_array and result_array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

What is the difference between `row_array()` and `result_array()`?

How would they be displayed on a view page?

```
if ($variable) {
    return $result->row_array();
} else {
    return $result->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html), `row_array` returns a single result and `result_array` returns multiple results (usually for use in a loop).

Examples from the documentation:

Result_array:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['title'];
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['body'];
}
```

Row_array:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   $row = $query->row_array(); 

   echo $row['title'];
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['body'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `result_array()`

   Returns the query result as a pure array. Typically you’ll use this in a `foreach` loop.
2. `row_array()`

   Returns a single result row. If your query has more than one row, it returns only the first row.
   Identical to the `row()` method, except it returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

**1) result_array():** return multidimensional array.

**2) row_array():** return one-dimensional associative array

So, if you display structured information of each of them you will get something similar to the following:

```
echo var_dump(result_array());
```

Output:

> array(1) {
>       [0]=> array(4) {
>           ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["title"]=> string(12) "News title 1" ["slug"]=> string(5) "slug1" ["text"]=> string(57) "In the name of
>   Allah, This is the first news description"
>       } }

```
echo var_dump(row_array());
```

Output:

> array(4) {
>       ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["title"]=> string(12) "News title 1" ["slug"]=> string(5) "slug1" ["text"]=> string(10) "description" }