# how to get next value without using foreach

Tags: php, sql

```
$stage=$this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT stages
   FROM ticket
   WHERE status='r'")->row_array(); 


$id=(int)$stage['stages'];
```

Comment: There is a library you are using here? Why not use a `foreach`?

Comment: I'm not sure why people put so much emphasis on not using loops like foreach, it is incredibly powerful and there isn't really much of a reason not to.

Comment: `next($stage)`? [PHP next() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php)

Comment: You can use `for($i=0;$i<count($stage);$i++)` but a foreach is a better way of doing it

Comment: @coderodour `while(next($stages))` then

Comment: @RomainBar Actually, you should declare `count($stage)` as a variable outside of the for loop, and use it that way. The way your code is currently written, `count($stage)` will be executed for every loop, which is inefficient. :)

Comment: @RomainBar not necessary to put that `next($stage)` inside a loop. A simple call to that function does indeed move the pointer 1 element ahead in the array. OP intends to achieve that, without a loop....for some reason.

Comment: without using any loop ,the next($stage) doenot work

Comment: You only want to have the next value. Therefore @coderodour 's comment is correct. Otherwise you have to be more specific.

Comment: when the use next($stage) it will cause following result,            [{"stages":false},{"person":null},{"charge":null}],"4":[{"stages":false},{"person":null},{"charge":null}]}

Comment: @noufal: This result looks strange. I guess you are using codeigniter (src: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=row_array#CI_DB_result::row_array) . According to the docs you need to specify, which row you want to fetch.

Comment: @noufal: another src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231354/difference-between-row-array-and-result-array

Comment: did not get the result,when use the next($stage)did not point the next array value                                                  $id=(int)$stage['stages'];$id=next($stage);